# How to update the state of tkiner menu cascade or command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

What is the best way to change the state of a tkinter menu or its children after the mainloop?

Thanks

Comment: So far menu.entryconfigure(1,state='disabled') seems to be working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configure it the way you configure all widgets, with the `configure` method:

```
widget.configure(state="disabled")
```

If you want to disable one of the items on the menu, use `entryconfig`:

```
widget.entryconfig(0, state="disabled")
```